# windows xp 32-bit netbeans issues

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I currently have a windows xp 32-bit with JDK 7 installed. I previously had installed netbeans IDE 7.1.3 Java SE kit, but deleted it so that I could download the full version. However, every time I have tried to download any version of the netbeans IDE, it says that either all the programs are already installed or that it just simply couldn't download the programs. I have searched around through my programs and found nothing netbeans-related, except in the add or remove programs, where it shows the netbeans IDE 7.3.1. I've tried several times to delete it, but it consistently fails. I'm fairly new to programming, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans also installs to the `AppData` folder, on Windows XP it's located in:

> C:\Documents and Settings\[[UserName]]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans

And on Vista and later for others with this problem:

> C:\Users\[[UserName]]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans

Replacing `[[UserName]]` with your current User profile name. This folder must be removed to completely reinstall NetBeans.